# How to use multiple IF

Tags: excel

I have a table that contains 10 product which is manufactured in several slots each day for 5 working days. I want to SUM them  in a new table for the first time it started to producing.

```
=IF(U11=0,0,SUM(U11:Y11))
```

The problem with this code it also SUM in the next cell so it is duplicated.

```
=IF(V11=0,0,SUM(U11:Y11)*IF(U11<>0,0,SUM(U11:Y11)))
```

In this case the duplication is solved but it multiply all others.

```
=IF(U11=0,0,SUM(U11:Y11)) 
=IF(V11=0,0,SUM(U11:Y11)*IF(U11<>0,0,SUM(U11:Y11)))
```

Expected result is the green and orange part contains the raw data.

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f2c9-0wmkpKOwGFF2gqwwJ2wLiNpkI69/view?usp=drivesdk]

Comment: As @ScottCraner said, you should use `AND()` or `OR()`. But to answer your question, if you need to nest multiple `=IF()` statements, you can do `=IF(V11=0, 0, IF(U11<>0, 0, SUM(U11:Y11)))`.

Comment: You helped a lot.
It was this: =IF(P12=0,IF(Q12<>0,SUM($M12:$Q12)),FALSE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AND()`

```
=IF(AND(V11<>0,U11=0),SUM(V11:Z11),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont understand you, but use multiple IF in that:

IF ( A1=0; TRUE ; FALSE )

IF ( A1=0; TRUE ; **IF ( A2=0; TRUE ; FALSE )** )        // this sample first if FALSE run 2. IF

IF ( A1=0 ; 
TRUE           // or 2. IF
;
FALSE      **IF ( A2=0; TRUE ; FALSE )**
)